# How to use only https in npm (urls as dependencies)

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I have a npm package with the a depndency that is shared in s3 (https://xxx.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yyy.tgz).

So in my PACKAGE.JSON

```
  "dependencies": {
    "zzz": "https://xxx.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx.tgz",
```

I want to use this in codesanbox or jsfiddle

I always have an anwser  like "Could not fetch dependencies, please try again in a couple seconds"

When I downlaod the package using a browser and I do this in my local projet:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "zzz": "file: xxx.tgz",
```

Every thing work well.

I noted that in npm we have only these possibilites

`<protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish> | #semver:<semver>]`

`<protocol> is one of git, git+ssh, git+http, git+https, or git+file.`

How can i use only HTTPS ?

Comment: `git+https` is GIT served through https.

Comment: not working, 
"zzz": "git+https://xxx.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yyy.tgz",

Comment: `git+https://xxx.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yyy.tgz`

Comment: my yyy.tgz is not a git projet, it is a npm package

Comment: git+https://xxx.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yyy.tgz its really not working